# mysql @@identity vs sql-server last_insert_id()

Tags: sql, mysql, sql-server, stored-procedures, dml

Am I correct in understanding that mysql's LAST_INSERT_ID() function doesn't reset between insert attempts (as @@identity does in sql-server)... that if the immediately preceding insert operation fails, LAST_INSERT_ID() will return the pk of whatever the pk of that connection's last insert to ***any*** table with an auto-incrementing primary key was.  And if I am correct in this, does this not seem like just about the most retarded behaviour for this function that one could come up with?  Is there no mysql function that behaves similarly to sql-server's @@identity?  One that will return NULL if the ***immediately preceding*** insert attempt creates no new record?  Alternatively, how does one know with certainty the primary key of the most recent insert operation?

Comment: @@identity gives you the most recent insert in ANY scope. This could be the result of a trigger that has nothing to do with the insert statement you just ran. in SQL server you generally want to be using the scope_identity() function.

Comment: @feihtthief - thx, good clarification +1

Comment: Please be aware that SQL Server's @@identity and scope_identity(), when used with multiple-row inserts on a server with multiple processors, can give incorrect answers! Using OPTION (MAXDOP 1) is a workaround.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@@identity is usually wrong in sql server as well.  You should be using `scope_identity()` in most cases instead.

In MySql, last_insert_id() should be safe to use because the only way you can call this function after an insert error is you've already correctly caught and accounted for the insert error.  Otherwise you would still be processing commands.  In other words, last_insert_id() is not your error-handling mechanism.

Comment: @paragraph 2 - makes me rethink the way i'm structuring the insert statement... in this case the where clause on the select statement that's feeding the insert determines whether an insert happens at all.  in other words, the insert is 0+ records depending on the where clause conditions.  i guess i can pull those outside the insert and conditionally perform the insert.  nice workaround, but it does feel like a workaround to me.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check to see if the insert was successful first. If the insert was successful, then you can rely on LAST_INSERT_ID().

edit: in php:

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('mydb');

mysql_query('<PUT YOUR INSERT HERE');
if(mysql_affected_rows()>0){
  $last_id=mysql_insert_id();
}else{
  //panic!
}
?>
```

Comment: i wonder if there's a native mysql function similar to php's msyql_affected_rows()?  all our dml resides in the database as stored procedures/functions.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php For other type of SQL statements, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, DROP, etc, mysql_query() returns TRUE on success or FALSE on error.

Comment: An insert statement could be "successful" and NOT do any inserting. Consider an INSERT IGNORE statement. In this case, relying on mysql_query()'s return value will produce the wrong outcome.